# jquery: add delay before effect

Tags: jquery, css-float

I have floating box on my site. I show it on mousenter and hide onmouseleave. Like this:

```
$(box).mouseenter(function(evt) {showBox();});
```

and

```
$(what).parent().mouseleave(function(evt) {hideBox();});
```

When I perform quick mouse move over the "box" it shows up. 
How not to show it in that case?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post hideBox And showBox aswell? And maybe do a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var showTimer;

$( box ).hover( function(){
    // wait .5 sec to show the box
    showTimer = setTimeout( showBox, 500 );

}, function(){
    // wipe timer so that showBox isn't called if < .5 sec
    if( showTimer ){
        clearTimeout( showTimer );
        showTimer = null;
    }

    hideBox();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your function call with setTimeout()

```
$(box).mouseenter(function(evt) { setTimeout("showBox()",1000);});
```

where 1000 is 1 sec. (1000 milisecond = 1sec)

Edit:

This might be a little more complicated then I thought. You have to prevent it from ever showing if mouse out quickly too.

```
var t;
$(box).mouseenter(function(evt) { t = setTimeout("showBox()",1000);});
$(box).mouseleave(function(evt) { clearTimeout(t); });
$(what).parent().mouseleave(function(evt) {clearTimeout(t);hideBox();});
function showBox(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    // the rest or your function
}
```

Comment: When you do a quick mouse over, it still shows, just 1 seccond later.
This you will need. but you also need to clear the timeout in your mouseleave. Right?

Answer (score 1):

I found the [bindWithDelay](http://briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/) plugin very useful for these kinds of scenarios.

It's vey easy to write something like:

```
$(box).bindWithDelay("mouseenter", function() { ... }, 500);
```

This adds a 500ms delay before the event fires. It handles all the plumbing of having to set/cancel/reset timers when the event fires multiple times.

(It also supports a handy *throttling* option for more complicated situations that you can read about in the link)

Comment: you'd still need to cancel the event

Comment: Yes, that is true, which can be done in the `mouseleave` event of course. The plugin is doing pretty much the same thing as the code posted in the other answers here. I just find it handy to have all the plumbing hidden away. Especially if you have several of these on one page.